# Website not opening because of HTTPS Everywhere. How do I fix the issue?

Tags: browser, website, browser-addons, safe-mode, https-everywhere

I was trying to open http://cbseacademic.nic.in/ in Firefox (90.0.2 (64-bit)) and Chrome (Version 92.0.4515.107 (Official Build) (64-bit)) in my Windows 10 laptop.

In Firefox, I got this error:

> ### The connection has timed out
>
> The server at cbseacademic.nic.in is taking too long to respond.
>
> - The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
> - If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
> - If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

[image: Screenshot of error shown in Firefox]

In Chrome, I got this error:

> ### This site can’t be reached
>
> **cbseacademic.nic.in** took too long to respond.
>
> Try:
>
> - Checking the connection
> - Checking the proxy and the firewall
> - Running Windows Network Diagnostics
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

[image: Screenshot of error shown in Chrome]

I tried accessing the website in a phone and the website opened. So there's no issue with the website.

I ran Firefox in troubleshoot mode and I was able to access the website.

Then I found that the issue was because of HTTPS Everywhere (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/https-everywhere/gcbommkclmclpchllfjekcdonpmejbdp, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/https-everywhere/), a browser extension.  Version of HTTPS Everywhere: 2021.7.13 (in both Firefox and Chrome).

Why is HTTPS Everywhere not allowing me to access http://cbseacademic.nic.in/ and how do I fix the issue?

Comment: Try disabling all of your extensions ... and then enable them again 1 by 1.

Comment: @DavidPostill I checked it. It is because of HTTPS Everywhere.

Comment: I have HTTPS everywhere enabled on Firefox and your site loads just fine.

Comment: That website does not appear to support the HTTPS port. Rather than sending a RST back, it just timesout. If it does support HTTPS, then I guess there is a L4 routing issue.

Comment: The website you are visiting does not support HTTPS. If HTTPS Everywhere doesn’t support creating an exception for a website, your only other choice, is to disable it temporarily when you visit the website

Comment: @DavidPostill What is your version of the extension? Mine is 2021.7.13.

Comment: @Bib What is RST? The website doesn't support HTTPS.

Comment: TCP RST packet, reset. Port blocked, no service on port etc...

Comment: @Bib I recall opening the website last month with HTTPS Everywhere on and it worked. But now it is not. So is this an issue of HTTPS Everywhere or the website?

Comment: Wipe it, then reinstall. Try another user, etc.

Comment: @RandomPerson - “I recall opening the website last month with HTTPS Everywhere on and it worked.” - Unlikely, the website isn’t responding to HTTPS, which tells me the server is configured to reject HTTPS entirely.  It’s possible it did work, but it doesn’t today, so contact the website administrator for more information (we can only tell you why HTTPS Everywhere doesn’t work today)

Comment: Mine is 2021.7.13

Comment: @Ramhound I don't have the contact details of the website administrator and I am unable to find it from the website.

Comment: There is “contact us” link on the website.  I see no reason that website would ever support HTTPS to be honest. The training portal itself supports HTTPS though

Comment: @Ramhound The contact us link doesn't contain details of website administrator. It contains details of people who work in the organisation in other positions. Please elaborate this: *"I see no reason that website would ever support HTTPS to be honest."*. Which "training portal" are you talking about? Are you talking about https://cbseit.in/cbse/training/?